# How to deploy vue-codeigniter separated logic app on shared hosting?

Tags: codeigniter, vue.js

let me explain the situation.
I have two front-end apps build with vue, one for client and other for admin.
And I build rest api with CodeIgniter.

As you see I have a separated logic here.
When I run build for the two apps and upload them along with the rest api to the server. 
It will not run !

Answer (score 0):

There is No logic to **Deploy Codeigniter**

Simply deploy it.